# What is wrong in my investment calculation

Tags: investing, investment

I am thinking to start investing monthly and i am trying to calculate my investment using excel with a compound interest of 5% monthly plus addition of certain amount.

First month investment is 10000 and from second month onwards i add monthly certain amount (1000/month or 5000/month).

But I am getting this weird result ([spreadsheet attached](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=41795306762900819822))

if I invest 1000/month (sheet 1) after 3 years I get 3.39 times more  profit comparing to 5000/month (sheet 2) which was just 2.8.

Assuming my calculation are not wrong, is it better to invest only a small amount monthly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you compute profit, in which you are not accounting for the timing of cashflows.

If you compute NPV's you get a better comparison. Also if you check the IRR, it will be 5% for both investments.